# HTML table reports having one row after programmatically adding rows

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
<div id="tableWrapper">
        <div id="tableScroll">
            <table runat="server" id="surveyTable">
                <tr>
                    <th>URL</th>                            
                    <th>Used</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tableFooter">
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport()">Export</a>
        </div>           

        <div>
            <input type="button" runat="server" id="btnUpdate" onserverclick="btnUpdate_ServerClick" value="Update" /> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

I add rows to this table in C# (a URL and a checkbox per row), after the page has rendered, users click on the checkboxes and when done, will click on the 'Update' button. Then we go to some code which should look through each row and get some data from each URL if the checkbox has been clicked.

The problem is that when I click the button there is only 1 row, the row on the HTML page. This is an issue with postback and I have tried to fight this with an UpdatePanel but no success so far. I added

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <triggers>
        <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="btnUpdate" EventName="ServerClick" />
    </triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

To the beginning and end but no joy. AJAX does work on the page as I tested this with this:

```
ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page)
if (sm == null)
{
    // ASP.NET AJAX functionality is not enabled for the page.
}
else
{
    // AJAX functionality is enabled for the page.
}
```

Can anyone advise why this isnt working?

Code to add HTML rows

```
foreach (var s in surveys)
 {
    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
    surveyTable.Rows.Add(row);
    HtmlTableCell urlCell = new HtmlTableCell();
    urlCell.InnerHtml = "url/Survey/" + s.stuff_id + "/" + s.stuff2_id + "/" + s.stuff3_id + "/";
    HtmlTableCell checkBoxCell = new HtmlTableCell();
    checkBoxCell.InnerHtml = "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"used\" " + (s.used == "Y" ? "checked" : "") + " >";
    row.Cells.Add(urlCell);
    row.Cells.Add(checkBoxCell);
}
```

Comment: post complete html code,i cant see the checkbox

Comment: Added the c# code that adds the extra rows on page_load

Comment: Why do you need the server to be involved with adding rows to a table in the first place? Why not do it with just JavaScript?

Comment: I get data from SQL, I add the data to each row.